# twisted.web.resource.Resource with twisted.web.template.Element example

Tags: python, twisted

I want to use twisted.web templates together twisted.web resources.

But I just don't get, how to make them work together.

I tried using, `flatten(request, MyElement(), request.write)`, but it ends up throwing an exception: `Request.write called on a request after Request.finish was called.`

Could someone provide me a very basic example how to use the two classes together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you forgot to return `NOT_DONE_YET` from your `render()` method, and therefore `finish()` was called for you immediately.  Something like the following should be somewhere in Twisted itself, to help with exactly this problem:

```
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.web.template import flatten
from twisted.web.server import NOT_DONE_YET

class ElementResource(Resource):
    def __init__(self, element):
        Resource.__init__(self)
        self.element = element
    def render_GET(self, request):
        d = flatten(request, self.element, request.write)
        def done(ignored):
            request.finish()
            return ignored
        d.addBoth(done)
        return NOT_DONE_YET
```

Comment: For future reference, the Twisted bug for documenting this is http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/4983

Comment: Thanks! I actually had 2 lines of code - 1st returned the flatten deferred, and the second returned NOD_DONE_YET. So I was absolutely sure, that I return NOT_DONE_YET!

Comment: Note that the linked bug is fixed and this bit of glue is available as of Twisted 12.1.0 as `twisted.web.template.renderElement`.